# change a variable in prefab from method called by the prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could you please advise me how to change a variable in prefab from method called by the prefab?
This is how I call the method from a prefab on collision:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
     {
         _GSScriptReference.EnemyCollision(transform.position, collision.gameObject.tag, collision, Lives, PointsForKillMe, gameObject);
     }
```

From Method in different script I want to change variable Lives in the prefab which called the method. I tried several syntaxes, none works for me. Now I have something like this:

```
 EnemyGameObject.GetComponent(FireballScript).Lives = Lives;
```

EnemyGameobject is the object reference 'gameObject' I got while calling the method -
Thanks so much for any help

Ukrutnik

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: When you instantiate a prefab in the scene, it has no references to other objects in the scene. So to find some other object you can use FindObjectOfType<T>(). Although, it is not an efficient way to grab a reference and you should avoid doing this method call every frame. It all depends on how do you architect your application. You should consider dependency injection patters or singletons. Describe better what do you want to achieve, define your entities and relation between them...

Comment: I'm a beginner so I might not have the best code architecture :). I have a main game script. It contains a method which every enemy is calling onCollisionEnter2D. I need to change number of lives of the enemy after the collision. I'm passing reference of the enemy gameobject as a parameter of the method call. I can't figure out how to change variable (nr. of lives) back in the enemy prefab.